# Java Server doesn't receive file from particular internet connection.Any Idea?

Tags: java, android, sockets, networking, client-server

I have built an android app which takes a pictures and send it to a server running on my pc using Java sockets. The Server receives the picture successfully when I send it from my android mobile using the same wifi network with the one that pc-server uses but it doesn't receive the image when I am sending it from another place using different network or when I use my mobile phone internet megabytes. It seems like image get lost on the way to the server because the android app runs properly and never get into catch{} code to throw an exception. Any idea????

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your pc server is using a WiFi router to connect to the Internet. That router is acting like a firewall that you need to disable so you can access from outside your WiFi network.

The best way is to open some port and forward it to your server:

http://www.wikihow.com/Set-Up-Port-Forwarding-on-a-Router

Then you could access from the outside. Remember to use the your external IP address and not the local one.

http://whatismyipaddress.com/es/mi-ip

Comment: In order to send the image from the same Wifi I need to use the local ip.

For all other users of my app I need a version of my app with the public ip as you said above.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this will solve your problem. but I had that problem before.
in my case, just like you, my connection worked on wifi, but never on my 3g mobile carrier internet.
it was a long time ago, so I don't remember exactly why, but adding "Content-Type", "charset=utf-8" to my headers solved my problem.

i was using volley, so basically my headers looked like this:

```
 @Override
        public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
            HashMap<String, String> headers = new HashMap<String, String>();
            headers.put("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
            return headers;
        }
```

for some reason, some specific carriers require to add utf encoding to the headers.

well, at least that was my own case.
give it a try :)